# How to use event listener in js to link to html?

Tags: javascript, html

How to add event listeners to the button on the page for the 'click' event?

Comment: You can add listeners using `addEventListener`. i:e `document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click',calculateBMI)`. Use `script` tag in your html to attach your js file to the html. i;e <script src="path to js file"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Call your method in the eventHandler of the Button

```
<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="calculateBMI()">Calculate BMI</button>
```

Other way would be te encapsulate fields and button under a `<form>` and add the function in the "onsubmit" event of the form.

Answer (score 0):

As from your question I can see that you want to link the js file with HTML file and use the event listener for calling the function.

Lets assume you have the HTML file with the name as **CalculateBMI.html** and js file name as **CalculateBMI.js**.

You can use the below code inside the HTML file head to connect the js file with HTML.

```
<script src="CalculateBMI.js"></script>
```

Once done you can change button input with below code with event as described below:

```
<button id="submit" onclick="calculateBMI()">Calculate BMI</button>
```

If you have any issue please let me know

Comment: Thank you for answering, but can I know how to use the event listener to make the function run when the button is clicked?

Comment: There are different types of event handlers in JS. You can use the below link to know more about them through this 
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)

Comment: **Event Listener** is used in different ways to call the function. Some are onclick, onhover, onblur, etc. these are used according to the needs. For your need **onclick** is the event handler which is used to call the function on **click**.